# How to perform website benchmarking?

Tags: nlp, web-scraping, benchmarking, sentiment-analysis, text-analysis

I am trying to do competitive analysis of online trends prevailing in real estate domain at state level in a country. I have to create a report which is not biased towards any particular company but it compares or just shows how the companies are performing for a list of trends. I will use parameters of `Clickstream analysis` to show the statistics of how the websites of the company perform. The trend specific performance can be depicted by `Sentiment Analysis` in my opinion. If there is some other way to do it in an effective manner I am looking forward to any such approach.

Now, I am not able to find any trends that come in common.

- **How can I find general trends which will be common for all real estate comapnies ?**

I tried using `Google Trends`. They provide graphical and demographic information regarding a particular search term and lists related terms to the search which I am clueless how to use. And as I drill down from country to state, the amount data is very less.

Once I have the trends then I've to find how people are reacting to those trends. `Sentiment Analysis` is the thing which will provide me this info.

- **But even if I get the trends how will I get trend specific data from which I can calculate its polarity ?**

Twitter and other social media sites can provide some data on which sentiment analysis can be performed. I used [this](http://twitrratr.com/) site which gives the positive, negative and neutral behaviour related to some term on twitter. I need something analogous to this but the dataset on which this analysis can be performed should not be limited to social media only.

- **Are there any other entities I can add in this competitive analysis
  report ?**

The report will be generated on monthly basis. And I want maximum amount of automation in above tasks. I am thinking of using web-scraping also to scrape data of similar format. I would also like to know what data I should scrape and what data I should manually extract.